# eclipse heap status keep high although no application is running

Tags: eclipse

1. Although no application is running in my eclipse, but the heap status still show 1105M, why?

[image]

*** edit on 20240205 to add log and avaiable software site in Install/update ***

the log as attached.
[image]

> > ENTRY org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core 1 16842760 2024-02-04 16:40:18.878 !MESSAGE Server Starting
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2024-02-04
> 16:41:50.998 !MESSAGE Connection to
> http://jope.ow2.org/update/jope/p2.index failed on No such host is
> known (jope.ow2.org). Retry attempt 0 started !STACK 0
> java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (jope.ow2.org)
> at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1084)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1075)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1071)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1006 2024-02-04
> 16:41:51.248 !MESSAGE Unknown Host:
> http://jope.ow2.org/update/jope/content.xml !STACK 0
> java.net.UnknownHostException: jope.ow2.org   at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 1000 2024-02-04
> 16:42:02.139 !MESSAGE No repository found at
> https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/4.3.x/.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 1000 2024-02-04
> 16:43:32.868 !MESSAGE No repository found at
> http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/.
>
> !ENTRY org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core 1 16842769 2024-02-04
> 16:44:43.256 !MESSAGE Server Startup Succeeded
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository 2 0 2024-02-04 16:47:25.306
> !MESSAGE Server returned lastModified <= 0 for
> https://raw.github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/master/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.updatesite/content.jar
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2024-02-04
> 16:47:30.208 !MESSAGE HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code
> (308):http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-p2-release/content.xml
> !STACK 1 org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.BrowseFileTransferException:
> HttpComponents connection error response code 308.    at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:293)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
> !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ecf.identity 4 0 2024-02-04 16:47:30.208
> !MESSAGE HttpComponents connection error response code 308.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository 2 0 2024-02-04 16:56:49.567
> !MESSAGE Server returned lastModified <= 0 for
> https://raw.github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/master/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.updatesite/content.jar
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2024-02-04
> 17:01:27.648 !MESSAGE Connection to
> http://jope.ow2.org/update/jope/p2.index failed on No such host is
> known (jope.ow2.org). Retry attempt 0 started !STACK 0
> java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (jope.ow2.org)
> at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
> at
> java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
> at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1084)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.access$0(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1075)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1071)
> at
> org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:74)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
>
> !ENTRY org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.wtp.core 1 16973825 2024-02-04
> 17:08:31.344 !MESSAGE Server processes have terminated prematurely.
> Please check your server logs for more details.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2024-02-04 17:14:55.866 !MESSAGE An
> internal error occurred during: "Cannot complete the request.
> Generating details.". !STACK 0 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
> space     at org.sat4j.core.VecInt.ensure(VecInt.java:309)    at
> org.sat4j.minisat.core.Solver.isSatisfiable(Solver.java:1888)     at
> org.sat4j.tools.SolverDecorator.isSatisfiable(SolverDecorator.java:114)
> at
> org.sat4j.pb.PseudoOptDecorator.isSatisfiable(PseudoOptDecorator.java:135)
> at
> org.sat4j.pb.PseudoOptDecorator.isSatisfiable(PseudoOptDecorator.java:161)
> at
> org.sat4j.tools.xplain.DeletionStrategy.explain(DeletionStrategy.java:118)
> at org.sat4j.tools.xplain.Xplain.explanationKeys(Xplain.java:113)   at
> org.sat4j.tools.xplain.Xplain.explain(Xplain.java:150)    at
> org.sat4j.pb.tools.DependencyHelper.why(DependencyHelper.java:363)    at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.Projector$ExplanationJob.run(Projector.java:143)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63) !SESSION
> 2024-02-04 17:25:26.413
> ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.11.0.I20190307-0500 java.version=12.0.1
> java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
> ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_HK Framework arguments:  -product
> org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32
> -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Comment: When you run an application that is actually run in a separate JVM and doesn't contribute to the Eclipse JVM heap size. The Eclipse heap will contain data from the many Eclipse plug-ins - things like indexes for all the Java classes

Comment: you mean when I run an application in eclipse, the application memory usage will not affect the figure shown in eclipse jvm heap ststus? but why I see the figure in eclipse heap status is so large? and even will show out of memory error and prompt to shut down eclipse.

Comment: Yes I mean that. I don't know why your Eclipse heap is so large, maybe a problem in one of the plug-ins you are using. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any memory related message. Or maybe you are just using plug-ins that need a lot of memory. Note that even a pretty minimal Eclipse install will use a heap of about 300-400 Mb.

Comment: just added the log before throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Well the error is in a "sat4j" plug-in - I don't know anything about that